# How to add time ranges in each cell in Excel?

Tags: excel, formula, date-range

I have an Excel sheet that a manager updates manually with agent's work times, every week. I want to be able to calculate the number of hours for all agents for each day.

The Excel sheet looks something like this:

```
 +-----------+-------------+-------------+-------------+  
 |    NAME   |  MONDAY     |  TUESDAY    | WEDNESDAY   |  
 +-----------+-------------+-------------+-------------+  
 |   John    | 8:30 - 17:00| 8:30 - 17:00| 8:30 - 17:00|  
 +-----------+-------------+-------------+-------------+  
 |   Peter   | 8:00 - 16:30| 8:00 - 16:30| 8:00 - 16:30|  
 +-----------+-------------+-------------+-------------+  
 |   Craig   | 9:00 - 17:30| 9:00 - 17:30| 9:00 - 17:30|  
 +-----------+-------------+-------------+-------------+  
 |   TOTAL   |      8:30   |      8:30   |      8:30   |  
 +-----------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
```

Is this even possible? It would save a lot of time for a lot of people if it can be done.

Comment: Will it ever be over midnight?

Comment: Why is the total hours for the three Monday entries only 08:30?

Comment: I am so sorry. I wrote 8:30 by mistake. I meant 25:30. I want the total hours. 8:30 would be the average.

Comment: No, it will never be over midnight.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use SUMPRODUCT() with LEFT and RIGHT to parse the data:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(RIGHT(TRIM(B2:B4),5)-LEFT(TRIM(B2:B4),5))
```

You will need to use a custom format on the output of `[hh]:mm`

[image]

Comment: That worked!!! Initially, it gave me the average. But when I changed the formatting to Custom - hh:mm:ss, I got the total hours:minutes:seconds.